# Access column in numpy array by for loop

Tags: numpy, for-loop

I am trying to store all columns of a numpy array in a variable by using a for loop (python 2). However, there is either a syntax error or I am required to define x.

This is what I have tried.

1)

```
x for x in train[:,x]:
  if x not in [target, IDcol]:
    predictors= x
```

2)

```
predictors = [x for x in train[:,x] if x not in [target, IDcol]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This code can't work.

Because you use `x` like a new variable but you already use it in `train[:,x]` !

Change your variables :

```
predictors = [x2 for x2 in train[:,x] if x2 not in [target, IDcol]]
```

Comment: When I do this, then there is still the error "name 'x' is not defined".

Comment: Because you have to define your `x`. What represent your `x` ?

Comment: I am not really sure. I tried to run the code from this website https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/03/complete-guide-parameter-tuning-xgboost-with-codes-python/

Comment: I just see `predictors = [x for x in train.columns if x not in [target, IDcol]]`.
Try `train.columns` or `train[:]` or `train[:,:]`.

If you would more help, tell me what contains `train`